# C# Firebase Restful Post generate unique key

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code that i used to do a POST request to firebase database.
What can i do, to allow the subsequence POST request to be in ascending order? I do not want the firebase auto generated unique ID.

Example can be viewed here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA2ne.png)

```
public void postEachFirebaseMessage(string dbcolName)
    {
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            user = "UserNameValue",
            message = "MessageValue",
        });
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"" + config.BasePath + dbcolName + ".json?auth=" + config.AuthSecret);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        json = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Found the solution. Just change request format to "PUT". It will not generate any unique ID.

Answer (score -1):

> I do not want the firebase auto generated unique ID.

If you don't want Firebase to auto-generate a unique key for you, you can generate your own unique key and then `PUT` data to that full URL. So something like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"" + config.BasePath + dbcolName + "/yourOwnUniqueKey" + ".json?auth=" + config.AuthSecret);
request.Method = "PUT";
```

But as said: you will need to ensure yourself that the key is unique. That is a completely valid scenario, but you will have to write the code for generating the unique keys yourself.

If you wonder why Firebase doesn't simply use keys like `0`, `1`, `2`, I recommend reading this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: "PATCH" request method solves the problem instead of "POST" for me since as discribed didn't olve the problem, but instead multiple calls generated multiple children under "yourOwnUniqueKey". Key is supposed to "update" not "insert new" record.

Comment: @Veljac A `PUT` and a `PATCH` both can write multiple child nodes under a location. The only difference is that `PUT` replaces all data under the location, while `PATCH `only updates the child nodes/properties that you specify in the request.